# Why is $\log_n(2)\cdot\log_n(4)\cdots\log_n(2n-2)\leqslant 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, induction, logarithms

> Prove that $\log_n(2)\cdot\log_n(4)\cdots\log_n(2n-2)\leqslant 1$.

I thought I might attack it by induction:
\begin{align*}
        \prod_{k=1}^{n}\log_{n+1}2k &= \bigg(\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\log_{n}2k\bigg)\big(\log_{n+1}(2n-2)\big)\big(\log_{n+1} n\big)^{n-1}\\[5pt]
        &\leqslant \big(\log_{n+1}(2n-2)\big)\big(\log_{n+1} n\big)^{n-1} \qquad \text{(by IH)},
    \end{align*}
and got stuck, since it's not obvious why this should be at most 1.

My intuition is that $\log_{n+1}(2n-2)$ is slightly above 1, but $\log_{n+1} n$ is slightly below 1, so repeatedly multiplying the former by the latter $n-1$ times should be enough to make everything at most 1.

But I can't seem to get the proof to work. I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: $$(\ln(\ln x))''=-\frac{\ln x+1}{(x\ln )^2}<0\quad(x>{\mathrm e}^{-1}).$$

Answer (score 7):

We prove $$\sqrt{\log_n(2k)\cdot\log_n(2n-2k)}\leq 1, \qquad 1\leq k\leq n-1.$$
Indeed, by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality), we have
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\log_n(2k)\cdot\log_n(2n-2k)}&\leq\frac{\log_n(2k)+\log_n(2n-2k)}2\\&=\frac{\log_n((2k)(2n-2k))}2\leq\frac{\log_nn^2}{2}=1,
\end{align*}
where we used that $(2k)(2n-2k)\leq\left(\frac{2k+2n-2k}2\right)^2=n^2$, which follows again from AM-GM.

As a result, we have
$$\log_n(2k)\cdot\log_n(2n-2k)\leq 1,\qquad 1\leq k\leq n-1.$$

Hence
\begin{align*}
\left(\log_n(2)\cdot\log_n(4)\cdots\log_n(2n-2)\right)^2&=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\log_n(2k)\cdot\log_n(2n-2k)\right)\leqslant 1,
\end{align*}
and therefore
$$\log_n(2)\cdot\log_n(4)\cdots\log_n(2n-2)\leq 1.$$